# Image Border Pixelation When Using zoomFactor on iPhone 11 Ultra Wide Lens

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

I'm building an app where I want to set some predetermined amount of zoom on the new iPhone 11's ultra wide camera. I'm currently doing the following:

```
// Construct the new capture device.
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInUltraWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
    captureDeviceVideo = device
} else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
    captureDeviceVideo = device
} else {
    return
}

do {                
    try captureDeviceVideo.lockForConfiguration()
    captureDeviceVideo.videoZoomFactor = 0.7 / 0.5
    captureDeviceVideo.unlockForConfiguration()
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

However, I see some strange pixelation/blurring around the border of the image (see below).

**This does not happen when I use the same zoom factor on a pre-iPhone 11 device (which falls back to using the built-in wide angle camera).**

[image]

Anyone else run into this issue? Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

I'm on iOS 13.2, Xcode 11.2 & Swift 4.2.